# nginx wont serve index.html in https

Tags: nginx

i'm trying to test some issues out, and it seems that the source comes down to not being able to serve an index.html file:

```
server {
    listen 4430 ssl;
    listen [::]:4430 ssl default ipv6only=on;
    server_name  avnav88website.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/_cert/etc/letsencrypt/live/avnav88website.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/_cert/etc/letsencrypt/live/avnav88website.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/_cert/etc/letsencrypt/live/dhparam.pem;

    location /hey {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html;
    }
    
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://abda_1;
        proxy_set_header Host avnav88website.com;
    
    }
}
```

when i go to avnav88website.com everything works.

when i try avnav88website.com/hey  i get a 404  -- instead of the nginx welcome site.

i even tried making index2.html with some wording, and still got 404 when i directed to that.

i must be missing something obvious..

Comment: Yes, nginx tries to find file `/usr/share/nginx/html/hey`, then checks if `/usr/share/nginx/html/hey` is a directory containing `index.html` file. Both checks failed, so you get 404 HTTP error. Check the difference between [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) nginx directives. If you want to get an `index.html` contents from the `avnav88website.com/hey` URL, you can use `location = /hey { alias /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html; }` block.

Comment: @IvanShatsky ahh ok i guess i confused the two..but with that i still get https://avnav88website.com:4430/hey even tho no 404 its blank

Comment: It should work. Check the error logs. You can also try to check if that location works at all: `location = /hey { return 200 'Hey!'; }`

Comment: @IvanShatsky that worked! it actually downloaded a file called hey...but i still have the issue of not being able to serve the index.html file...https mysite.com:4430/hey/ is unreachable.
ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Comment: @IvanShatsky it's also kind of weird, because out of the box this works without the https config and just 1 server block

Comment: Last example does not download any file, it just returns HTTP 200 Ok code with the `Hey!` content written inside the nginx configuration. I don't know why my first example not working for you, sorry.

Comment: @IvanShatsky ok after some playing around, i found out that if i type website.com/hey it wont work.... if i type website.com/hey/ it will.  is there a reason for this? and how do i allow for both do you happen to know? thanks!

Comment: I think it can be done via HTTP 301 redirection: `location = /hey { return 301 /hey/; }`